# Read Apollo Client Cache after it updates in another component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I'm guessing this isn't an issue at all, but expected behavior, but wanted to double-check before adopting a different solution.

I have 2 components that render on the same page

```
<Navigation /> // 1st Component
<MainContent /> // 2nd Component
```

The 1st component makes a GraphQL Query to fetch the current user, adding the logged-in user to the Apollo Client cache. (In my `ApolloClient` the cache is using `InMemoryCache`)

```
const { data, loading } = useQuery(MeDocument);
```

The 2nd component is used to fetch the cached data to check if the user is logged in, without making the same redundant GraphQL query again.

```
import { useApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';
.....
const client = useApolloClient();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(client.cache.readQuery({ query: MeDocument })); // log is `null`
}, [client]);
```

However, the value from `useApolloClient` in the 2nd component doesn't update when the cache updates in the 1st component after the initial GraphQL Query completes. However, if I added a bit of a delay before reading the cache, or if the cache is read after a click event, or doing something like below, it does get the value, but this seems very hacky and unreliable.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  delay(300).then(() => console.log(client.cache.readQuery({ query: MeDocument }))); // log is not null
}, [client]);
```

I am guessing this is expected behavior, or is there a solution to this?

I was perhaps going to go down the route of adding the `data` property from the `useQuery` in the 1st component to update a redux reducer so that value can be consumed in the 2nd component. But was curious if this was possible without the need of a redux store?